# Стоит ли задавать в вопросе оффтоп?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

Есть такая ситуация: у меня есть вопрос и мне просто интересно узнать мнение сообщества о той или иной вещи, связанной с вопросом, но сама по себе эта вещь не является автономной, т. е. без оригинального вопроса задавать её бессмысленно <s>(только на mail.ru)</s>.

Пример: я хочу на мете задать вопрос, связный с SO, при этом я заметил связь SO как сервиса с остальными сервисами в чём-либо: системе голосования, формате постов и т. д. – и я задал 2 вопроса: 1-й, указанный выше, и 2-й, в духе: «Как вы *считаете*, почему многие современные сервисы подчиняются какой-то тенденции (этой же тенденции подчиняется и SO)?»

Как вы *считаете*, стоит ли "прикреплять" подобный описанному выше тесно связанный оффтопик к оригинальному вопросу?

Comment: Я считаю, что если уж дорвался до меты то стоит задавать сразу 3 вопроса, а по ходу обсуждения этих трех вопросов - задавать новые, которые появятся при обсуждении. Потому что - кто если не мы?

Comment: Нет, не стоит. Оффтоп не приветствуется, будьте готовы к тому, что его удалят и оставят только онтопик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нет, не стоит. Оффтоп не приветствуется, будьте готовы к тому, что его удалят и оставят только онтопик

<sup>@Kromster</sup>

Нет, не стоит. Оффтоп не раскрывает сути вопроса и только ему мешает. Внедрение оффтопа в вопрос не оправдывается, я б сказал, а только вредит.

С оффтопом есть 3 пути:

- Не добавлять его в вопрос и забыть о нём как о страшном сне
- Если формат оффтопа позволяет, извлечь его из исходного вопроса и включить в новый вопрос
- Найти другой тематичный сайт/форум и задать его там. Понятие оффтопа относительно: что на SO оффтоп, то на другом форуме онтоп.

---

<sup>*Примечание*: Данный ответ – вольная интерпретация [комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10619/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%84%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf/10626?noredirect=1#comment44916_10619) от @Kromster</sup>

Comment: Четвёртый путь: задать оффтопичный доп. вопрос в чате, в общей или тематичной комнате. Не совсем эффективно, т.к. обычно мало посетителей в чате. Совет: добавте в оффтоп немного "краски", например, пожалуйтесь на модераторский произвол, сразу посетителей в чате будет более чем предостаточно.

Comment: @0xdb "добавте в оффтоп немного "краски" – больше похоже на какие-то махинации...

Comment: Не совсем так, привлечь внимание, добавить немного рекламы для оффтопа. Но если рекламу считать махинацией мозгов, то да.

Comment: @0xdb ваш 4-й путь уже описан в 3-м пути: "Найти другой тематичный сайт/форум и задать его там". Чат это и есть отдельный сайт.